# Wordpress A-Z search result

Tags: php, wordpress

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710532/how-to-add-a-z-filter-to-wordpress-search-result) I am trying to add an A-Z directory where it will just list posts that start with the relevant letter using the TwentyEleven theme and I'm struggling. I have added the code to search.php and added the links. These display OK, but when I click on a letter it just refreshes and goes to the home page (the links are on the home page).

The link is in the format www.domain.com/?&letter=t

Does anyone have any ideas?